# Why does my iterator point to null, but only sometimes?

Tags: c++

I need to write some classes to implement Context Free Grammars in my code.
CFGs have production rules of the format "lefthand side -> righthand side". They are implemented as follows:

```
class GrammarProduction{

  public:

  Nonterminal mLhs;
  std::vector<GrammarSymbol*> mRhs;
```

I want to store my production rules in a std::set to make sure no one can add duplicate rules.
To make duplicate detection work, I implemented the operator< for GrammarProductions as shown below.

```
bool GrammarProduction::operator<(const GrammarProduction& other) const{
  if (mLhs < other.Lhs()) return true;
  if (mRhs.size() < other.Rhs().size()) return true;
  std::vector<GrammarSymbol*>::const_iterator it1, it2;
  it2 = other.Rhs().begin();
  for(it1 = mRhs.begin(); it1 != mRhs.end(); it1++){
    std::cout << (*it1) << std::endl;
    std::cout << (*it2) << std::endl;
    if(**it1 < **it2) return true;
    it2++;
  }
  return false;    
}
```

Running this code gets me a segmentation fault at line

```
    if(**it1 < **it2) return true;
```

because the pointer *it2 is null. However, if I change the line which prints *it2 to

```
    std::cout << (*it2) << other.Str() << std::endl;
```

it works just fine and *it2 is not null. I have no idea why that is and any advice would be greatly appreciated.
If it is necessary to post the functions which are called, I will do so. I haven't because I hope it's not important to the question and it will be a rather large amount (for a post, at least).

Edit: I've narrowed down the problem and it boils down to this

```
bool GrammarProduction::operator<(const GrammarProduction& other) const{
  std::vector<GrammarSymbol*>::const_iterator it1, it2;

  it1 = mRhs.begin();
  std::cout << "it1:" << std::endl;
  std::cout << (*(mRhs.begin()))->Str() << std::endl; //output (1,2,2)
  std::cout << (*it1)->Str() << std::endl; //output (1,2,2)

  it2 = other.Rhs().begin();
  std::cout << "it2:" << std::endl;
  std::cout << (*(other.Rhs().begin()))->Str() << std::endl; //output (1,2,2)
  std::cout << (*it2)->Str() << std::endl; //Segmentation Fault

  //do whatever
  return false;
}
```

Comment: Hint: You might want to check if `it2 == other.Rhs().end()`.

Comment: Beat me to it @Xeo. You're probably continuing past the size of other.Rhs

Comment: No, and this would not explain how printing other.Str() would fix it. The iterator can't overflow because of "if (mRhs.size() < other.Rhs().size()) return true;"

Comment: Hmm, good point, I missed that. Do you compile in debug mode and with which compiler? Both MSVC++ and GCC provide checked iterators for debugging that might tell you what's up. Otherwise, undefined behaviour in another part of your code is likely.

Comment: What is the return type of `Rhs()`?

Comment: I've narrowed down the problem (see the edit). The line which causes the segfault and the preceding line should be exactly the same. That being said, I haven't tried the debug mode. Compiler is g++, and I've never used the debug mode before, will read into it.

Comment: Return type of `Rhs()` is std::vector<GrammarSymbol*>.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're invoking undefined behaviour. Since your `Rhs()` function returns the vector *by value*, it's destroyed at the end of the full expression:

```
//          vvvvv -- created here
it2 = other.Rhs().begin();
//          gone here -- ^
```

This makes `it2` a *dangling iterator*, which is basically the same as a dangling pointer. Dereferencing this iterator will cause UB. To fix, make the return type a reference:

```
std::vector<GrammarSymbol*>& Rhs(){ return mRhs; } // depending on your needs
std::vector<GrammarSymbol*> const& Rhs() const{ return mRhs; }
```

Answer (score 2):

You should check for `it2 == other.Rhs().end()` in the loop. If you increment the iterator past the last element, dereferencing it is invalid and will likely cause a segmentation fault.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! "if (mRhs.size() < other.Rhs().size()) return true;" makes sure that it2 will never reach the end, so checking it is unnecessary.

Answer (score 1):

```
if(**it1 < **it2) return true;
it2++;
```

is not very good because in your for loop you don't check if it2 reach the end of list.

a version that should work will be :

```
bool GrammarProduction::operator<(const GrammarProduction& other) const{
  if (mLhs < other.Lhs()) return true;
  if (mRhs.size() < other.Rhs().size()) return true;
  std::vector<GrammarSymbol*>::const_iterator it1, it2;
  it2 = other.Rhs().begin();
  it2End = other.Rhs().end();
  for(it1 = mRhs.begin(); it1 != mRhs.end(); it1++){
    std::cout << (*it1) << std::endl;
    if (it2 == it2End ) return true;
    std::cout << (*it2) << std::endl;
    if(**it1 < **it2) return true;
    it2++;
  }
  return false;
```

}

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Unfortunately, this can't be the problem and your code doesn't work either. "if (mRhs.size() < other.Rhs().size()) return true;" makes sure that it2 will never reach the end.